# Javascript animation causing high cpu useage

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm are using the ScrollMagic library and the GreenSock Animation Platform to create a single page scrolling animation.

Here is an example of the code for the animation:

```
// Initiate Scroll Magic
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

// This pins the main container for the duration of the animation
new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: "#main", triggerHook: 'onLeave', duration: 59000
    })
    .setPin("#main", {pushFollowers: true})
    .addTo(controller);

//Create scenes at specific points using the offset of the pinned conainter...
new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#main", duration: 500, offset:1000})
    .setTween("#diseaseInitiation", 0.5, { opacity: 1}) 
    .addTo(controller);

new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#main", duration: 500, offset:1000})
    .setTween("#initialKeratinocytes", 0.5, { opacity: 1}) 
    .addTo(controller);

new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#main", duration: 500, offset:2000})
    .setTween("#initialKeratinocytes", 0.5, { top:100})
    .addTo(controller);

new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#main", duration: 500, offset:2000})
    .setTween("#diseaseInitiation", 0.5, {top: -100})
    .addTo(controller);
```

The actual animation is a lot more complex and there are about 100+ scenes.

While I appreciate it's going to be quite processor intensive it seems to be using way more than expected and slows down my machine.

Is there anything obvious here that would affect performance?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what exactly you want to get out of this? Is the animation clippy? Slow? Etc? Please specify what you're looking for.

Comment: Run a javascript profile on your site it will give some fairly detailed info on the functions that are causing high CPU usage. 

Here's the link for Chrome's profiler: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling

Comment: *The actual animation is a lot more complex and there are about 100+ scenes.* - That would affect performance greatly.

Comment: Thanks for the dev tools profiler link, I will have a look into that. The animation runs ok, I'm looking to bring down the cpu usage. I thought that the high number of scenes would have something to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are seeing high CPU usage is due to animating the `top` CSS property. When animating it is always better performance to use `y` instead of `top` and `x` instead of `left`. This way you animate using the GPU and not the CPU.

Change both of your last two animations from `top` to `y`

```
new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#main", duration: 500, offset:2000})
.setTween("#initialKeratinocytes", 0.5, { y:100 })
.addTo(controller);

 new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#main", duration: 500, offset:2000})
.setTween("#diseaseInitiation", 0.5, { y: -100 })
.addTo(controller);
```

Here are some articles explaining why its better to animate using transforms versus position with `top`, `right`, `bottom`, or `left`

[Myth busting CSS animations vs Javascript](https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/)

[Why moving elements with translate is better than posabs topleft](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)

[Jank Free](http://jankfree.org/)

It is always best practice when animating to keep your animated properties to transforms and opacity so they render on their own layer and provide much better performance, and less jank.